# How disable box-shadows and borders in video.js Player

Tags: css, video.js

When I click play button, subttitles button or fullscreen button, That shows a blue border or blue box-shadow, so every video.js player have that, i want to disable that i have try like this but is not working!

```
.video-js .vjs-volume-panel .vjs-volume-control.vjs-slider-active.vjs-volume-vertical .vjs-volume-bar,
    .video-js .vjs-`big-play-button`,
    .vjs-flat-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control,
    .vjs-flat-skin .vjs-subtitles-button,
    .video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button {
      border: none !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

so this code i think is not corect, so i need an other CSS code to disable all those blue borders, or box-shadows? [image: IMG]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma from the selector and back-ticks from "big-play-button"

```
.video-js .vjs-volume-panel .vjs-volume-control.vjs-slider-active.vjs-volume-vertical .vjs-volume-bar,
.video-js .vjs-big-play-button,
.vjs-flat-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control,
.vjs-flat-skin .vjs-subtitles-button,
.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button { /*Remove comma from end*/
 border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/0a5u3ew4/834/

Here is the original video: http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/0a5u3ew4/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i think my code is not corect to disable that what i want! `.video-js .vjs-volume-panel .vjs-volume-control.vjs-slider-active.vjs-volume-vertical .vjs-volume-bar,
.video-js .vjs-big-play-button,
.vjs-flat-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control,
.vjs-flat-skin .vjs-subtitles-button,
.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button` so maybe this is not corect!

Comment: @Fonsi your code is correct but needs some modifications. Check the updated answer

Comment: in this case,can only help a person who knows very well video.js CSS

Comment: @Fonsi Check  http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/0a5u3ew4/834/. It contains your code and it works